# Open Google Maps infowindows automatically for all of the markers and markerclusters

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I have Google Map created with version of Google Maps api v3. It's "standard" Google Map, filled with markers and clusters. Every marker and cluster have it's own InfoWindow, showed when end user click on it.

What I need is that when map is loaded, to open all of InfoWindows of all markers and clusters showed on map.

Right now, they are showed only when I click on them:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerGreenCluster, 'clusterclick', function(markerGreenCluster) {

  var content = '';
  var info = new google.maps.MVCObject;
  info.set('position', markerGreenCluster.center_);
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  aIWgreen.push(infowindow);
  var center = markerGreenCluster.getCenter();
  var size = markerGreenCluster.getSize();
  var markers = markerGreenCluster.getMarkers();

  // more code goes here...

})
```

I noticed that problem is in cluster definition, and method **`markerGreenCluster.getSize();`** It returns number of grupped markers, and it can return it after whole map is loaded, or something like that.

Can you help me how can I achieve that all of InfoWindows are open (showed) when map is loaded?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `info` object?

Answer (score 0):

the infowindows only open on click because you're only creating them on the click event listener.  Move the code creating the infowindows out of the click handler, into a window load event handler instead.

Comment: yes, but in that case, i get only a size of a last created cluster (number of markers in a last created cluster, and that is not enough).

Answer (score 0):

To do this, what I do is create a InfoWindows object and stored it into the marker. Something like this

```
function CreateMarker(Lat, Lng, Title, Content) {
  var aInfoWin = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: Content,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Lng)
    });

  var aMarker = new StyledMarker({
    title: Title,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Lng),
    MyInfoWin: aInfoWin
    });

  aMarker.MyInfoWin.open();
}
```

You can access to the Marker InfoWindows where you like (events, code,.....) like the other properties.

Code non tested, only to get the idea

Regards